# mysql query, select the top comment according votes

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables `comments` | `votes`

```
the `votes` structure 
[`id` | `user_id` | `comment_id`  | `rating`]
```

and the comments has the comment_id as the primary ok?
now i want get the top comments according to the sum of rating

**[rating is 0 or 1]**

and i want to get the top users too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top Comments

This assumes comments table has a column named comments_id
SELECT A.* FROM comments A INNER JOIN (SELECT comment_id,SUM(rating) sumrating FROM votes GROUP BY comment_id) B USING (comment_id) ORDER BY B.sumrating;

This assumes comments table has a column named id
SELECT A.* FROM comments A INNER JOIN (SELECT comment_id,SUM(rating) sumrating FROM votes GROUP BY comment_id) B ON A.id = B.comment_id ORDER BY B.sumrating;

Top Users

This assumes users table has a column named user_id
SELECT A.* FROM users A INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id,SUM(rating) sumrating FROM votes GROUP BY user_id) B USING (user_id) ORDER BY B.sumrating;

This assumes users table has a column named id
SELECT A.* FROM users A INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id,SUM(rating) sumrating FROM votes GROUP BY user_id) B ON A.id = B.user_id ORDER BY B.sumrating;

Top Users and Comments

This assumes comments table has a column named comments_id and users has a column named user_id
SELECT B.* , C.* FROM
(SELECT comment_id,user_id,SUM(rating) sumrating FROM votes GROUP BY comment_id,user_id) A
comments B,users C,
WHERE A.comment_id=B.comment_id
AND A.user_id=C.user_id
ORDER BY A.sumrating,C.user_id,B.comment_id;

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Unknown column 'user_id' in 'from clause'

Comment: Unknown column 'comment_id' in 'from clause'

Comment: @moustafa I am sorry. The USING clause assumes that both aliases A and B have a column named comment_id in the first query, and user_id in the second query. I added queries not using the USING clause.